# Equation returning NaN value

Tags: javascript

I honestly don't understand why this doesn't work. Haven't seen anything close enough to my project to help me.
This function:

```
    function sneakPast(){

    sneakChance = Math.floor((Math.random()*11)+1)+sneak;
    alert(sneakChance);
    if (sneakChance >=(6*level))
    {
        sneakSuccess = true;
    }
    else {sneakChance = false;}
}
```

is being called from this function:

```
function sceneFourC(){
    sneakPast();
    if (sneakSuccess == true){document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML = "You are able to sneak past the mob into town. <br/><input type='button' value='Continue.' onClick='sceneFive();' />";}
    else {document.getElementById("Content").innerHTML = "You fail to sneak past the mob.<br/><input type='button'/>";}



}
```

When the alert comes up it just displays "NaN."

Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to have set the `sneak` variable anywhere. Are you sure it's a number, and not a string? Also, where is it coming from? Is it **really** accessible to the function?

Comment: Case sneak as number, Number(sneak)

Comment: Where's the variable "sneak" being set?

Comment: Are you defining this variable prior to using it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. All variables are declared at the beginning of the document so they're available to all functions.

Comment: Wait, I just found the problem. When sneak is given a value, it is given the value within a function, so when another function tries to call the variable, the value is undefined.

Comment: @Nate Could you add an alert in your function to call "sneak", just to check if the function is able to access it?

Comment: @user990156  That's what I did, and "sneak" is undefined, so I have to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, The sneak is not defined and so it is 'undefined'.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3kUzM/1/) here

Assign an integer to sneak and it should work.

Change

```
var sneak, sneakSuccess = false;
```

to

```
var sneak = 0, sneakSuccess = false; //assign a valid integer to sneak
```

Comment: Yeah I will, it says I have to wait another minute before I can, since the question was solved so promptly.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the fundamental problems is that you're setting `sneakChance` to `false` instead of `sneakSuccess`.  That said, there are other issues too:

Try this:

```
function sneakPast() {
    var sneakChance = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11) + 1) + sneak;
    return sneakChance >= (6 * level);
}

function sceneFourC() {
    var content = document.getElementById('Content');
    if (sneakPast()) {
         content.innerHTML = "You are able to sneak past the mob into town. <br/><input type='button' value='Continue.'/>";
    } else {
         content.innerHTML = "You fail to sneak past the mob.<br/><input type='button'/>";
    }
}
```

i.e.

1. have `sneakPast()` *return* success, rather than set a global variable
2. don't repeat yourself in the `sceneFourC` function.

You have a load other global variables too (`sneak`, `level`, etc), but we can't clean those up without a lot more context.